# how to set the progress bar before showing result?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to implement code for set the Progress  bar before displaying the result in the same activity. .. My issue is want to Show Progress Dialog Before Setting Image And Before Starting Video.... help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think it works this way : Either preExecute() and postExecute() method of AsyncTask where in preExecute() just show the progressDialog and in postExecute() dismiss the same. or Use Handler to show progress dialog and dismiss the same

Answer (score 3):

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
private class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            });
            //your code

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        //result

    }
}
```